# C programming. 10 pairs per line?

Tags: c

My program has to print 10 pairs per line.  However, it prints 10 pairs per line sometimes and another times it doesn't.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I read the book chapter twice. I understand how module operation works, but it looks like I can't use it very well here.  What am I missing here?

This is what I have written:

I would like to know why is not printing 10 pairs per line all the time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch;
int i=0; /* counter */

printf("Please enter some characters.\n\n");

while((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
{
if((i%10) == 0)
    putchar('\n');   /*printf("\n); */

if (ch == '\n')
    printf( "\n\\n ");
else if (ch == '\t')
    printf("\\t %d ", ch);
else if (ch < ' ')
    printf("^%2c %3d  ", ch+64, ch);
else
    printf("%2c %3d  ",ch, ch);

i = i+1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem lies here:

```
if (ch == '\n')
    printf( "\n\\n ");
```

When you encounter a newline in your input, you will output a newline followed by the characters `\` and `n`.

But what you *don't* do is adjust `i` to indicate you've started a new line. So, if you're first newline is the fifth character, `i` will still be 5 and you'll less than ten characters on the next line.

In addition, I think you still want to be outputting the ASCII codes for newline and tab, and the formatting needs some work.

The sample below is for your education only. If you plagiarise it, you're likely to be found out pretty quickly, so read it and understand it. Don't copy it blindly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please enter some characters.\n");

    while((ch=getchar()) != EOF) {
```

So far, that's pretty much the same as yours, now we get a little different. Rather than `i % 10 == 0`, we simply run the numbers continuously between 0 and 9 inclusive. That will stop problems when you have more than two billion or so characters in your input :-)

```
        // Ten characters printed? Newline and adjust count.

        if(i == 10) {
            putchar('\n');
            i = 0;
        }
```

Now the only real change is formatting and the actions for newline. It must end up with `i` being set to zero after printing so a combination of the newline-specific `i = -1` and the `i++` below that every case goes through will do that:

```
        // Handle each case.

        if (ch == '\n') {
            // Newline? Print and reset to 0 (after i++ below).

            printf( "\\n %3d\n", ch);
            i = -1;
        } else if (ch == '\t')
            // Tab? Just print tab symbol.

            printf("\\t %3d  ", ch);
        else if (ch < ' ')
            // Control character? Print ^X.

            printf("^%c %3d  ", ch+64, ch);
        else
            // Otherwise just print character as is.

            printf("%2c %3d  ", ch, ch);

        // Increment count.

        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run:

```
pax> echo 'This
...> input crosses many lines, some larger than ten,
...> some smaller.' | ./testprog
Please enter some characters.
 T  84   h 104   i 105   s 115  \n  10
 i 105   n 110   p 112   u 117   t 116      32   c  99   r 114   o 111   s 115  
 s 115   e 101   s 115      32   m 109   a  97   n 110   y 121      32   l 108  
 i 105   n 110   e 101   s 115   ,  44      32   s 115   o 111   m 109   e 101  
    32   l 108   a  97   r 114   g 103   e 101   r 114      32   t 116   h 104  
 a  97   n 110      32   t 116   e 101   n 110   ,  44  \n  10
 s 115   o 111   m 109   e 101      32   s 115   m 109   a  97   l 108   l 108  
 e 101   r 114   .  46  \n  10
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I did not realized I had to reset my counter.  ONce you guys pointed that out, I quickly got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you start a fresh line upon finding a newline character, you don't reset `i`.  I would suggest the following change:

```
if(char == '\n')
{
    printf("\\n  10  ");
    i = -1;
}
```

The `i = -1;` resets the counter; accounting for the fact that it will be incremented at the bottom of the loop (`i = 0; continue;` would also work).  Now, newlines are all handled by the check for `i%10==0`, so I took the newline out of the `printf`.  I also added in the ASCII code for the `'\n'` so it conforms to the specs.

A few other changes I would make:

If you change the increment to `i = (i + 1) % 10`, you will eliminate the slight possibility of `i` overflowing.

When you're printing the tab character, there's no need to use formatting to print the ASCII code;

```
printf("\\t   9  ");
```

will do the same thing, and may be slightly faster depending on how well your compiler optimizes it.

To ensure things line up nicely when they're printed, I would print non-printable characters with

```
printf("^%1c %3d  ", ch+64, ch);
```

This is purely aesthetic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did not realized I had to reset that counter.  It is great that we all can learn a lot from each other in this website.

Answer (score 0):

To not forget: after the loop:

```
if((i%10) == 0)
    putchar('\n');   /*printf("\n); */
```

The error is:

```
printf( "\n\\n ");
```

Should be:

```
printf( "\\n ");
```

Followed by:

```
else if (ch < 32) {
    if (1 <= ch && ch <= 26) {
        printf("Ctrl+%c ", 'A' - 1 + ch);
    } else {
        printf("Ctrl+%c ", 'A' - 1 + ch); // Whatever
    }
}
```

Especially on Windows `\r' could occur.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realized I had to reset the counter. After I reseted the counter life was better.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a newline in the input itself ur program wil output a new online. That way there might not be 10 characters in the output always

Answer (score -1):

your program print the whitespace while it is running ~you should add the else if statement to jump over the whitespace character~
the code should be like this~

```
else if(ch == ' ')
continue;
```